# Simple build system: run command if directory changed

Tags: software-development

I have a complex, heterogeneous project with a bunch of build systems involved already. Scala code is built with SBT, JavaScript with Gulp, there are Dockerfiles, Python tests, documentation generation, and shell scripts.

Everything is great, except I want to save time by not rebuilding stuff that has not changed. So I am looking for a build system with one simple feature: I want to define that directory `X` depends on directory `Y`, so that if something in `Y` has changed, it needs to re-run command `C` to update `X`.

I thought this would be a basic feature in all build systems, but it is not. Most build systems require me to tell them about all the output files. I want to be able to work on the directory level instead. Most build systems think in terms of *source files* and *compilers*. I just want to run arbitrary commands.

I have looked at a number of build systems and eliminated them already. But I don't want to list them. It is entirely possible that I eliminated one just because I missed a little feature.